# CORS firebase storage issue with Angular 2 issue

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

**What is expected:** When accessing firebase storage bucket, receive data with no error in the console log.

**What happens:** Error in console log of the type `Access to fetch from origin 'http://localhost:4004' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Answer (score 2):

1. On [the cloud dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/) click on "Activate Cloud Shell" button.
   [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKlUO.png)
2. Click on "Open editor" button. [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgjBS.png)
3. Right click on 1a, click on "New File" and call it cors.json and add the following. [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXaZq.png)

```html
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

4. Click on "Open Terminal". [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiGC4.png)
5. Paste the following

```html
gsutil cors set cors.json YourBucketUrl
```